Need help finding the analytical solution to the eigensystem problem for interacting systems
Consider the case where we have a matrix $\mathcal{H}_1$ ($n\times n$ dimensions) that describes a particular system. We bring two similar systems  close to one another and we want to see how they interact. This can be done by using a coupling matrix $T$. Then the complete system would be characterized by a matrix of the form
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=\begin{pmatrix}
h&T\\
T^\dagger&\lambda h
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad h=matrix,\ T=matrix,\ \lambda=scalar.
\end{equation}
To make things easier, let us consider a system ($h$) composed of $n$ identical elements that are placed on a line with a constant distance between them. To reduce the complexity of the problem, we use the  nearest neighbor approximation (so that $h$ is a tridiagonal matrix) and also assume that there is no onsite potential (to consider only the couplings). Based on all of these, I would like to understand the 2 possible configurations that are presented in the link:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/82f33QlT.png
In the first case ($\mathcal{H}_1$), the $h$ and $T$ matrices are given by
\begin{equation}
h=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
k_1&0&k_1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&k_1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&k_1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&k_1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
k_2&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
while in the second case ($\mathcal{H}_2$), these matrices  are given by
\begin{equation}
h=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
k_1&0&k_1&\cdots&0&0\\
0&k_1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&k_1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&k_1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
k_2&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&k_2&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&k_2&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&k_2&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&k_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}.
I cannot find the analytical solution to neither of these problems. The only think that I can say is that in the second matrix, by making various permutations ($1\rightarrow1,n+1\rightarrow2,2\rightarrow3,n+2\rightarrow4,\cdots$) the problem can be re expressed in the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}_2\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_2\\
k_2&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
&
\begin{pmatrix}
k_1&0\\
0&\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}&\cdots
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
k_1&0\\
0&\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}
&
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_2\\
k_2&0\\
\end{pmatrix}&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Originally I thought that I could use Blocks theorem to solve this problem. But unfortunately it doesn't help me that much. Could someone help me?

From the title I guess you want to solve a problem of the form $Ax=\lambda x$. What is that problem exactly?

Yes correct. Let's say n=2 then the matrices are
\begin{equation}
\matcal{H}_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_1&0&0\
k_1&0&k_2&0\
0&k_2&0\lambda k_1&0\
0&0&\lambdak_1&0
end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&k_1&k_2&0\
k_1&0&0&k_2\
k_2&0&0\lambda k_1&0\
0&k_2&\lambdak_1&0
end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
